# How to know where to place a block in the body of my page

Tags: theming, blocks

I am new to drupal7 and I am trying to create blocks and new content on the body in drupal7 using css and php. Can you help with directions please.
 Thank you

Comment: provide details plz.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to Drupal 7, I also encourage you to look into placing your blocks using the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module, rather then hard-coding their location through theming or something like that.  It's also more flexible than what you can just do through the block admin interface.

Here's a simple example of using the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module to place a block in a certain location on a single page or a specific content type:

1. Once you've downloaded and enabled the module, go to admin/structure/context
2. Click the "Add" link to add a new context
3. Fill in the first few fields as shown below (name, tag, conditions to be met to fire this context)

[image]

4. Before saving, in the "Reactions" section, select **which blocks** you want displayed and **WHERE** when the conditions above are met

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Content you can create from your Content types in admin menu, basic content types are like `Article` or `Basic page`. [Here](http://drupal.org/node/120635) you can read about how to add content.
If you need block with just static view you can easy create it in admin menu `Structure -> Blocks -> add block`, also you can create custum blocks, you need to write module, or create blocks with [Drupal Views Module](http://drupal.org/project/views). How to create blocks read [here](http://drupal.org/documentation/blocks).

In admin menu `Structure -> Blocks` you can chose region where to place your block on your page, also you can add your own regions on the page. [Here](http://megadrupal.com/blog/add-new-regions-in-drupal-7-themes) are example of how to create new region on the page.